# MNIST - dataset preparation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am working on MNIST dataset for machine learning, and I have 2 csv files. One containing data and the other one labels (from 0 to 9).
How do I reshape and add the labels so that I can use it for machine learning prediction?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MD3z.png) (labels)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ljc6.png) (images)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use sklearn datasets instead.

Comment: I cant use sklearn for this

Comment: As we don't know about the csv format, we don't know how how you read you data, the question is too broad and cannot be answered.

Comment: I have included images of the data

Comment: This doesn't explain what the data is, what a row is, how you end up with one column instead of an image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models
from keras import layers

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.rashape((60000, 28*28))
train_labels = train_images.astype('float32') / 255
test_images = test_images.rashape((10000, 28*28))
test_labels = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```